# No me permite renderizar a la primera

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, axios

Estoy intentando renderizar de forma aleatoria en la home los pokemons, las peticiones las realizo a la pokeapi. Me sucede que no renderiza a la primera y cuando quiero indicar en los corchetes finales que renderice cada vez que se cambia la variable min o dataURL se genera un loop infinito que crashea todo, dejo el código debajo agradezco ayuda

````
  const min = Math.floor(Math.random() * 806 + 1);

  const [dataURL, setDataURL] = useState([]);
  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {

    const getURL = async () => {

      try {
        const res = await axios({url: `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=20&offset=${min}`})
        const {data} = res;
        setDataURL(data.results)
        
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }

    const getPokemon = async () => {

      try {
        getURL() 
        const res = await axios.all(dataURL.map(({url}) => axios.get(url)))
        setPokemon(res);
        
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }

    return getPokemon(); 
    
  }, [])```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Siempre que estes escuchando un estado en el useEffect y dentro lo estas modificando se va generar un loop infinito sino le pones una condición que lo detenga, no es necesario crear un estado para la url si la vas consultar simpre, si tu objetivo es consultar pokemones cada que cambies de pagina entonces solo necesitas el estado de pagina y de pokemons
intenta poner una bandera de status

```
const min = Math.floor(Math.random() * 806 + 1);

  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({elements:[],
status:"STATUS_NO_LOADED"});

  useEffect(async() => {
if(pokemon.status==="STATUS_NO_LOADED"){
   
        const res = await axios({url: `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=20&offset=${min}`})
        const {data} = res;
        

        const res = await axios.all(res.results.map(({url}) => axios.get(url)))
        setPokemon({...pokemon,status:STATUS:"LOADED",elements:res});
    }
  }, [min])
```